# how to iterate over a shapefile in node.js

Tags: node.js, shapefile

I have the following node.js code which reads a shapefile based on code from (https://github.com/mbostock/shapefile)

```
var shp=require('shapefile');
var path="polygons.shp"
var encoding="utf8"

function readRecords(path, encoding) {
  return function() {
  var callback = this.callback;
  shp.read(path, encoding, function(error, header, records) {
  callback(error, records);
});   }; };

var rs = readRecords(path,encoding)
console.log(rs)
```

when I execute the above code I get : undefined

any idea of how do I iterate over such object?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the header before you move into reading the records. This bit of code logs the entire shapefile to the console:

```
var shapefile  = require( 'shapefile' ),
    reader = shapefile.reader( 'polygons' );

var logger = function( error, record ) {
  console.log( record );
  if( record !== shapefile.end ) reader.readRecord( logger );
}

reader.readHeader( logger );
```